# changing datetime in a string format to just the data in string format

Tags: java

Im receiving data in a string format like this:

`"2018-08-31T00:00:00Z"`

and I want to change it to only the date without the time:

`"2018-08-31"`

what would be the right way to do it?

should I just remove what after the T in the string or parse it to DateTime and add a format (but then I will have to change to a string again)

how would you go about this?

thought about something like this:

```
val myDate = "2018-08-31T00:00:00Z"

val res = myDate.substring(0, myDate.indexOf("T"))
```

Comment: Simplest solution is to use subString to get the 10 first characters from the string, `dateString.substring(0, 10)`

Comment: the simplest solution is string manipulation - but you should be sure that the format does not change. If you are sure, then there is no need for `myDate.indexOf("T")` because it won't change either. Use the `substring` as proposed in the other comments-

Comment: You can do this `myDate.split("T")[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is best to keep data in the most specific format possible and only convert when you need for display or integration purposes. So in this case it might be best to store the value as a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` - the Z in your initial value probably indicates GMT or +0 offset. And then only when you need to convert it to a String using the `format(DateTimeFormatter)` method. You can convert your initial value to an `OffsetDateTime` with this

```
OffsetDateTime osdt = 
    OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-08-31T00:00:00Z",
       DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

String output = osdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

Comment: *FYI:* Right, `Z` is for [*Zulu Time Zone*](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z) that is just UTC±0. You don't need to pass a formatter to `.parse(` as the given string is a standard format.